# Center top most textframe VBA powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

so I have this line of code which works fine for just 1 ppt-file.

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment=ppAlignCenter
```

How can i make this work for all powerpoint files in the same folder with VBA? So that it knows that it selects the top most TextFrame and then AlignCenters it.

Or even when all PPTs are open if that's easier..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will select the shape that is positioned closest to the top of the slide:

```
Option Explicit

' Selects the shape that support text which is closest to the top of the slide
' Written by Jamie Garroch of YOUpresent Ltd (http://youpresent.co.uk)
Sub SelectHigestTextShape()
  Dim oSld As Slide
  Dim oShp As Shape, oShpTop As Shape
  Dim sShpTop As Single

  On Error Resume Next
  Set oSld = ActiveWindow.View.Slide
  If Err Then Exit Sub
  On Error GoTo 0

  ' Set the top to the bottom of the slide
  sShpTop = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight

  ' Check each shape on the slide is positioned above the stored position
  ' Shapes not supporting text and placeholders are ignored
  For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
    If oShp.Top < sShpTop And oShp.HasTextFrame And Not oShp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
      sShpTop = oShp.Top
      Set oShpTop = oShp
    End If
  Next

  ' Select the topmost shape
  If Not oShpTop Is Nothing Then oShpTop.Select msoTrue

  ' Clean up
  Set oSld = Nothing
  Set oShp = Nothing
  Set oShpTop = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but it seems that it doesn't work when I say that it should do this for all open workbooks.